# Is it safe to pass ConcurrentDictionary type into a function that takes IDictionary?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I have a method:

```
void foo(IDictionary<string, object> data) {
    data["key1"] = getValue1();
    data["key2"] = getValue2();
}
```

I currently call it as follows:

```
var serialDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foo(serialDict);
```

Now I need to call `foo` with a `ConcurrentDictionary` type because the dictionary is being populated on multiple threads.

```
var concurrentDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foo(concurrentDict);
```

Since `ConcurrentDictionary` implements `IDictionary`, I do not have to change the signature of the `foo` method. And the change seems to work fine on my machine.

However, something doesn't sit well with me about being able to populate a regular dictionary and a concurrent dictionary in the same manner/method.

Is what I am doing safe?

Comment: i cant see why it wouldnt be OK. Concurrent Dict says that it can be used wherever IDictionary can - it says so by implementing that interface.

Comment: "Safe" under what operations? Is your program adding those keys on one thread and reading from them on another thread?  Do you have an ordering requirement that the reader run after the writer?  Because those invariants are not maintained by your code. The concurrent dictionary **will not crash your process** under a race condition, but that doesn't mean that your program is automatically *correct*!  You are required to treat the dictionary as *constantly changing* unless you have written code that keeps it still.

Comment: @EricLippert Not those same keys and I have ordering instructions.  Other threads do add or edit keys, but not the ones in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you do, in the method, if you just modify the dictionary using the indexing operation, it should be fine as the semantic of indexing setting is add or update and the dictionary should do this in a thread safe manner. 
If your method does more complicated things such as checking for the existence of a key and then adding a value if it does not exist, then that might result in unexpected results if multiple threads are writing to the dictionary (`ConcurrentDictionary` has dedicated overloads for add or create value, that are atomic)

Your method may also get confused if it adds to the dictionary and then expects to read the value from the dictionary and another thread modifies the same key.

So the short answer is, generally is should be fine but you need to analize your method for concurrency issues if the method was not created with thread safety in mind.